# R: ggplot (x,y,z) create multiple linear regression lines for different z values

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have an interpolated DF with **x, y and z** data.

*x values ranges between -250 and +2000, Y values between -2 and +2 and z values between 75 and 90.*

With ggplot2 I've created a 2D plot (geom_raster) with **fill = z** which results in a heatmap for the different z values.

Now I want to create multiple linear regression lines for different z-values (e.g. a "lm" for z = 80, z= 85, and so on) and add them over the geom_raster plot including a legend.

How can I do this?
Please tell me if I didn't specify something exactly.

edit:
this is how my ggplot looks like:

```
plot <- interpdf %>%
  filter(!is.na(z)) %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, group = z)) + 
  geom_raster( aes(fill = z), interpolate = FALSE, alpha=alpha) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-200,2300))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1.8,1.5))+
  geom_contour(color = color, alpha = 0.1) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="YlGnBu", na.value="white")
```

whereas the interpdf data  looks like this:

```
   x      y       z
---------------------
-2100    -2.4    83.5
956.4    -1.3    84.3
1255.1   1.34    88.9    
...      ...     ...
```

Here is what my plot looks like:
[image]

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide a MRE. But I would look into `geom_smooth()`

Comment: I added my code for the ggplot, hope this helps, or what else do you need?

Comment: Please add the necessary data. Look at past answers to see how to create artificial data in case you cannot provide `dput(interpdf)`. .

Comment: I've added the interpdf data, hope this makes it clear

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100,10),z=rep(1:4,25))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_smooth(data = df, aes(x=x,y=y, group=z, colour=z), se=F)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it didn't work. Not sure why. I will add my plot as an image to the question!

Comment: Without some sample data we cant really help you any further. So please use `dput(interpdf)` tp provide some.

Comment: Check the upload again. It is not complete.

Comment: Don't know why but I cant just copy and paste it. Other option would be to save it as `interpdf.RData` and upload that file

Comment: what do I have to do to allow a geom_smooth?

Comment: Why do you want to regress a single value on another single value? There is nothing to be smoothed. You could just divide `y` by `x` and you have the slope of this pair of points.